# Replacing CRLF with LF in Ant regex

Tags: java, replace, ant, eol

I want to replace windows eol (CRLF) with Linux eol(LF) in Ant. I cannot find a way to use a regex that selects the Windows eol characters.

I tried a lot of different things and nothing seems to work.

```html
<replaceregexp byline="true">
  <regexp pattern="\r\n" />
  <substitution expression="\n"/>
  <fileset dir="${basedir}/mydir" includes="**/*" />
</replaceregexp>
```

Comment: Ant's [**`<fixcrlf>`**](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html) task might also help.

Comment: @Mandy8055 thank you very much this solved my problem. The answers above i already tried and sadly they didnt work.

Comment: @Mandy8055 yes, working like a charm.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew; sorry to question your edit but with due respect I want to know why you removed `regex` tag from the question? I guess this problem can also be solved using regex too. Isn't it? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Mandy8055 If it could be solved with a regex, it would have worked with what OP tried. From the docs, I inferred that `\s+` does not match newlines.

Comment: Okay @WiktorStribiżew but maybe XML entities inside regexp might work. I cannot test it myself right now; but once I used `&#10;` and `&#13;`. Although I'm not sure whether this might work for OP right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the Ant's [**`<fixcrlf>`**](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fixcrlf.html) task which is specifically created for this purpose.

```
<fixcrlf eol="unix" srcdir="${basedir}/mydir" includes="**/*" />
```

This tasks has many advantages one of which is; it automatically repeats itself without using `\r`.